# Map elements to list of unique indexes

Tags: python, list, unique

Suppose I have a list of elements:

```
my_list = ['CatA', 'CatB', 'CatC', 'CatA', 'CatA', 'CatC']
```

and I want to convert this list to a list of indexes of unique elements.

So `CatA` is assigned to index 0, `CatB` to index 1 and `CatC` to index 2.

My desired result would be:

```
result = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2]
```

Currently I'm doing this by creating a dictionary that assigns to each element it's unique `id` and then using a list comprehension to create the final list of indexes:

```
unique_classes = np.unique(my_list)
conversion_dict = dict(unique_classes, range(len(unique_classes))
result = [conversion_dict[i] for i in my_list]
```

My question is: Is there an easier and straightforward way of doing this?

I am thinking about having a big list of categories so it needs to be efficient but preventing me to manually create the unique list, the dictionary and the list comprehension.

Comment: numpy.unique is a method for this (I don’t remember which kwarg has to be set to True but it is in the numpy docs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @mikey, you can use `np.unique`, as below:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = ['CatA', 'CatB', 'CatC', 'CatA', 'CatA', 'CatC']

res = np.unique(my_list, return_inverse=True)[1]
```

Result:

```
[0 1 2 0 0 2]
```

Comment: Yes, I like this solution. I didn't know about this option in np.unique

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
my_list = ['CatA', 'CatB', 'CatC', 'CatA', 'CatA', 'CatC']
first_occurances = dict()
result = []

for i, v in enumerate(my_list):
    try:
        index = first_occurances[v]
    except KeyError:
        index = i
        first_occurances[v] = i
    result.append(index)
```

Complexity will be *O(n)*.

Basically what you do is storing in `dict` indexes of first value occurance. If `first_occurances` don't have value `v`, then we save current index `i`.

Comment: Downvotes, can you also tell what is wrong with the answer and why this answer is not usefull?:)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using Label encoder from scikit learn.It will assign labels to each unique values in a list.

Example code :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
my_list = ['CatA', 'CatB', 'CatC', 'CatA', 'CatA', 'CatC']
le = LabelEncoder()
print(le.fit(my_list).transform(my_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
result = [my_list.index(l) for l in my_list]
print(result)
[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2]
```

list.index() returns the index of first occurrence as required for your task.

For more details check [list.index()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: Yup, but this is pretty inneficient